# iOS 9 `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` and `overflow: scroll` breaks scrolling capability

Tags: ios, css, safari, webkit, touch

I'm developing a webapp and I've got a div inside of an iFrame that has hidden, overflowed content that I want to be scrollable.

On Safar on iOS 9 when I add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` to the div (that already has `overflow-y: scroll;` to give the scroll a fluid feel, it breaks and doesn't scroll at all.

I know that this is a known issue but I haven't found solutions relevant to my scenario: I have iFrames that do more than transmit data, they actually contain content for the user. Orientation doesn't matter, the content will always need to be scrollable.

Comment: Have you tired specifying `overflow-y` in the `body` tag  like this `body {overflow-y: scroll;}` that might work as it will applied through out the site instead of just on a single `div`

Comment: @BrentWhite no, that doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Were you able to solve this yet? Post a fiddle up so I can see the issue.

Comment: @BrentWhite it's hard for me to show a fiddle as this is a big nest of iframes

Answer (score 17):

I just ran into this issue with dynamic content within a div that had `overflow: auto` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

Dirty, ugly workaround: force the content inside to be bigger than the scrolling div when added to dom. Something like this:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <div style="min-height: 101%">
        dynamic content
    </div>
</div>
```

My theory is that Safari tries (needs) to do some heavy optimizations when `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` is added, and these don't play nice with some types of dynamic content.

Comment: Wow, so dirty, so filthy.. it worked. Thanks Christopher, I spent 2 hours changing heights & overflows until i saw your hack

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This is the perfect solution for the situation. Worked here too!

Comment: Wow! Worked for me!

Comment: In 2019: I still run into the same issue. Is there any progress for fixing this in safari or an alternative solution approach?

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue with `webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on iOS9. It can be reproduced on an device or the iOS simulator. As Christopher Camps mentions, it only happens with dynamic content, i.e. content that changes from being smaller then the scrollable container to larger then the container.

[Heres a CodePen demonstrating this issue](http://codepen.io/t-kelly/full/qOowZR/), including Christopher Camps fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems another hack for this Safari bug is to use javascript to set a `style="overflow: none"` and reset it back to its previous value immediately after.