# Unable to create scrollable area inside a scrollable area on ios

Tags: ios, css, scroll

The following code works fine on desktop and android mobile however it does not work on ios. I would appreciate any help to get me in the right direction.

https://jsfiddle.net/slash197/047c4dj8/6/

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.holder {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 128px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.row {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        left,
        rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.0)   0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0) 100%
    );
}


<div class="holder">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do? What you have tried?

Comment: @Ankur_009 Thanks for the negative vote. What I'm trying to do is in the title, what I have tried is the code I provided along with jsfiddle link to test it.

Comment: Did you intentionally leave the -webkit-scrolling-overflow rule out of the js fiddle? If I'm using the code you posted above, the scroll works as it should in iOS, however your fiddle code does not.

Comment: Why the Android tag ?

Answer (score 3):

IOS Safari is ignoring the width in percentage change it into px and it will start working check the fiddel link below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            .holder {
                position: relative;
                width: 1000px;
                height: 100%;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                overflow-x: hidden;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch !important;
            }
            .content {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 128px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch !important;
            }
            .row {
                width: 3000px;
                height: 100px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
                    left,
                    rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.0)   0%,
                    rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0) 100%
                );
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pe6t29kf/11/

Comment: the scrollbar will not be visible on ios mobile devices but scroll will work by swiping left or right.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your listed code you set the `.row` class with a pre-defined `width`, thereby ensuring every `<div>` element with that class will require a scroll. I'm assuming it's the horizontal scroll that fails, correct? I don't have an iPhone, but I noticed someone mentioned that the above code works in iOS. Is it possible that in the actual code the content requiring a horizontal scroll is dynamically generated?

If so, have you tried to force the content to always be marked to scroll, similar to what you did above, by setting a fixed `width` or `min-width` property, possibly to a percentage > 100%?

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row" style="min-width: 101%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not an expert on iOS, but if it involves dynamically generated content, it's possible the problem could be an iOS scrolling quirk related to this issue.

[iOS 9 `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` and `overflow: scroll` breaks scrolling capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897960/ios-9-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch-and-overflow-scroll-breaks-scrolling)